# Why does this codes stuck and doesn't work (javascript)

Tags: for-loop, error-handling, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

This simple code makes me crazy.
It doesn't work in any browser or JSFiddle. The page won't be responsive and gets stuck.

https://jsfiddle.net/dckkj4uu/6/

Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    First number:<br>
        <input type="number" id="fir">
        <br>
    Second number:<br>        
        <input type="number" id="sec">
        <br>
    Increment:<br>        
        <input type="number" id="inc">
        <br>        
    </p>
        <button id="btn">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", me);


var first = document.getElementById("fir");
var f = first.value;
var second = document.getElementById("sec");
var s = second.value;
var inc = document.getElementById("inc");
var ic = inc.value;

var str = "";

function me(){
    for(var i=f; i<=s; i=i+ic){

        str+=i;

    }
return document.write(str);}
```

It always crashes

**Edit:** JSlint says no error

Comment: Is .value an integer or string?

Comment: All the .value are integer but maybe also float

Comment: I had this problem, then I simplified it to this code in order to know from where does the error come... so simple loop from user-defined to user-defined with user-defined increment, but I was surprised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call initialize 'f = first.value' outside the event handler there won't be any value assigned to f because the code executes when the page is loaded, not after you've clicked on the submit button. Same goes with 's' and 'ic'.

This should fix the issue:

```
function me(){
    var f = parseInt(first.value);
    var s = parseInt(second.value);
    var ic = parseInt(inc.value);
    for(var i = f; i <= s; i = i + parseInt(inc.value)) {
        str += i;
    }
    return document.write(str);
}
```

Comment: does this parseInt make no problem when the input is float?

Comment: It will convert the value to an integer. You can change everything to parseFloat if you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks I converted all to parseFloat, I will search more for such a problem, I am still beginner, therefore I was surprised, sry I can't upvote.. thank you again